# Does windows subsystem for linux detects usb wifi adapter?

Tags: kali-linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am thinking of buying a usb wifi adapter but i'm not sure if it'll be useful when im using wsl

Comment: Why would you even need this? Windows is in charge of networking, not the WSL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)

Comment: @Panki To use it to audit wifi networks using wifite? You can't use the adapter the host machine use.

Answer (score 2):

Windows Subsystem for Linux (sometimes called Bash for Windows) inherits networking from Windows.  Just type "ip addr show" and you will see the same networking information as Windows.  Linux programs in WSL have the same access to your local network and the internet that Windows programs have.

You can certainly add a USB WiFi adapter if you like. It should work for both Windows and WSL. However, WSL will not see it as a USB device or be able to control it directly. It will only be available for networking. If you really want to use the USB WiFi adapter with Linux drivers, you will need a full Linux virtual machine such as Virtual Box.